# How to highlight only file name when renaming file in Krusader?

Tags: rename, krusader

When I renamed files (by F2) in Krusader on Ubuntu 10.10, only the file name got highlighted for renaming, not the file extension. After I upgraded to Ubuntu 11.04, the whole file including extension is highlighted.

Before (10.10): **it_crowd_subtitles**.srt

After (11.04): **it_crowd_subtitles.srt**

It's not a big deal, but I miss the original functionality. Is there any way how to set the file highlighting so only the file name gets highlighted when renaming files in Krusader?

**update:** it's the same on Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go to `Settings`->`Configure Crusader`->`Panel` and uncheck `Rename selects extension`.

[image]

Comment: It was there all the time, right under my nose! Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I've used krusader since 9.04 - but I've never really noticed (or paid attention) the selection behavior. I just checked, the issue may not be with krusader - but with KRename.

Comment: I think that issue is with Krusader, not with KRename - that's used as an external app with batch renaming, not for single renaming. (+1 anyway, because you gave me the reason to check out KRename and it's an awesome app :))

Comment: oops! typo - the issue _my_ not be with krusader -> the issue _may_ not be with krusader ; sorry